# Solspace Calendar Limit Occurrence Returned

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a list of upcoming events which I'm pulling by using {exp:calendar:cal}. Is there a way I can limit recurring events so only the first one displays? Using occurrence_count doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in this thread: [Solspace Calendar: Only show next occurrence of recurring event in list of recurring and non-recurring events](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19684/solspace-calendar-only-show-next-occurrence-of-recurring-event-in-list-of-recur/19686#19686)

Based off this thread, a tutorial on creating a chronological list with unique occurrences can be found here: http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/190596/articles/4000020599-how-to-display-a-chronological-list-of-events-with-each-unique-event-appearing-only

**Summary**:

One approach is to use PHP to create an array of unique events, and display your event data only when the event is encountered for the first time in {exp:calendar:cal}. Here's an example (turn on PHP for your template and set it to Output):

```
{!-- Create the arrays --}
<?php 
    $event_ids = array();
    $event_data = array();
?>

{!-- 
    // Check if the event was already encountered (i.e. is in the array),
    // and store your data in a separate array if this is the first time
    // encountering this event 
--}
{exp:calendar:cal /* your other parameters here */}
<?php 
    if( ! in_array('{event_id}', $event_ids) )
    {
        $event_ids[] = '{event_id}';
        $event_data[] = '* The data you want displayed *';
    }
?>
{/exp:calendar:cal}

{!-- Display event data, still in chronological order --}
<?php 
    foreach($event_data as $data)
    {
        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Of course there are likely other strategies, using PHP, Stash, or other means, but the main idea is to create a list/group/array of unique events within your timeframe.