# solspace calendar: only display the first occurrence of each recurring event within a set timeframe

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

EE 2.8.1 Calendar 1.8.6

I want to only display the first occurrence of each repeating event.

Right now I have a list of all events always displaying the next upcoming occurrence.

```
{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="{embed:calendar_id}" event_limit="{embed:event_limit}" date_range_start="today" show_months="6" pad_short_weeks="n" dynamic="off"}
<li><a href="{path='events/event'}/{event_id}/">{event_title} - Details >></a> {event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"} 
{if event_summary}<br />{event_summary}{/if}
{if event_location}<br />Location: {event_location}{/if}
{if event_cost}<br />Cost: {event_cost}{/if}<br /><br />


</li>
          {if no_results}
          <li>No events could be found within the specified time range for this Calendar.</li>
          {/if}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Comment: Try updating to 1.8.9. That's the latest version. Also **turn on Template Debugging** and check that `calendar_id=""` and `event_limit=""` are parsed correctly (i.e. are not showing `{embed:...}`). In particular, make sure you have `event_limit="1"` to show 1 event. Lastly, does your event start "today" or a date before that? In other words, is your first event before "today"?

Comment: Yes it is more than likely that the event has started before today.

Also if I have event limit set to 1 it will only show a single repeating event.  I have numerous repeating events and I want to display the first event for each even if it has already happened.

Comment: In that case, you might want to change the title of this thread from "_...only display the first event of **a** recurring event_" to "_...only display the first event of **each** recurring event_". Or even better "...only display the first **occurrence** of **each** recurring event **within a set timeframe**. I'll go ahead and make the edit to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution, from the Solspace support site, might be what you are looking for:

[How to display a chronological list of events, with each unique event appearing only once](http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/4000004901/articles/4000020599-how-to-display-a-chronological-list-of-events-with-each-unique-event-appearing-only)

It's also been mentioned in these threads:

- [Solspace Calendar Limit Occurrence Returned](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24269/solspace-calendar-limit-occurrence-returned/24271#24271)
- [Solspace Calendar: Only show next occurrence of recurring event in list of recurring and non-recurring events](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19684/solspace-calendar-only-show-next-occurrence-of-recurring-event-in-list-of-recur/19686#19686)

**Summary**:

One approach is to use PHP to create an array of unique events, and display your event data only when the event is encountered for the first time in {exp:calendar:cal}. Here's an example (turn on PHP for your template and set it to Output):

```
{!-- Create the arrays --}
<?php 
    $event_ids = array();
    $event_data = array();
?>

{!-- 
    // Check if the event was already encountered (i.e. is in the array),
    // and store your data in a separate array if this is the first time
    // encountering this event 
--}
{exp:calendar:cal /* your other parameters here */}
<?php 
    if( ! in_array('{event_id}', $event_ids) )
    {
        $event_ids[] = '{event_id}';
        $event_data[] = '* The data you want displayed *';
    }
?>
{/exp:calendar:cal}

{!-- Display event data, still in chronological order --}
<?php 
    foreach($event_data as $data)
    {
        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Of course there are likely other strategies, using PHP, Stash, or other means, but the main idea is to create a list/group/array of unique events within your timeframe.